# CSS- semi-transparent layer over map not working

Tags: css

i am not sure if this is possible, but i would like to add a semi transparent layer over a map. Then place text over the layer. I have tried the following, but the layer is behind the map instead of over it and so is the text, how do i get around this?

```css
/*GOOGLE MAPS*/

section#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
/*layers*/

.layer {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;
  /*netscape*/
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  /*IE*/
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
  /*IE 8*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id='map'>
  <div class="layer">

    <h3 id="area">Restaurants delivering to</h3>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // When the window has finished loading create our google map below
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

      function init() {
        // Basic options for a simple Google Map
        // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
        var mapOptions = {
          // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
          zoom: 11,
          // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400), // New York

          // How you would like to style the map. 
          // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
          styles: [{
            "featureType": "all",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [{
              "visibility": "off"
            }]
          }, {
            "featureType": "landscape",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
              "visibility": "on"
            }, {
              "color": "#f3f4f4"
            }]
          }, {
            "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
              "weight": 0.9
            }, {
              "visibility": "off"
            }]
          }, {
            "featureType": "poi.park",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [{
              "visibility": "on"
            }, {
              "color": "#83cead"
            }]
          }, {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
              "visibility": "on"
            }, {
              "color": "#ffffff"
            }]
          }, {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [{
              "visibility": "off"
            }]
          }, {
            "featureType": "road.highway",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
              "visibility": "on"
            }, {
              "color": "#fee379"
            }]
          }, {
            "featureType": "road.arterial",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
              "visibility": "on"
            }, {
              "color": "#fee379"
            }]
          }, {
            "featureType": "water",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
              "visibility": "on"
            }, {
              "color": "#7fc8ed"
            }]
          }]
        };

        // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
        // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
        var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

        // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

        // Let's also add a marker while we're at it
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400),
          map: map,
          title: 'Snazzy!'
        });
      }
    </script>

    <!-- FLAT DESIGN MAP -->
</section>
</div>
```

Only the map shows and nothing else in the browser. But i want it to look like this.

[image]

Comment: After map is created innerHTML of section#map was overwritten. Place your layer outside the section#map

Comment: @DimaFitiskin thank you. that worked

Answer (score 0):

If you give your main section position relative like below, you can then give your layer position absolute including top and left values, as seen below, also as opposed to reducing the opacity of the layer just use an rgba value in your background-color instead:

** Also I would move the h3 out of the map section and put it above.

```css
/*GOOGLE MAPS*/

section#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  position:relative;
  margin:auto;
}
/*layers*/

.layer {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h3 {
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<section id='map'>
  <div class="layer">

    <h3 id="area">Restaurants delivering to</h3>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // When the window has finished loading create our google map below
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

      function init() {
        // Basic options for a simple Google Map
        // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
        var mapOptions = {
          // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
          zoom: 11,
          // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400), // New York

          // How you would like to style the map. 
          // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
          styles: [{
            "featureType": "all",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [{
              "visibility": "off"
            }]
          }, {
            "featureType": "landscape",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
              "visibility": "on"
            }, {
              "color": "#f3f4f4"
            }]
          }, {
            "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
              "weight": 0.9
            }, {
              "visibility": "off"
            }]
          }, {
            "featureType": "poi.park",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [{
              "visibility": "on"
            }, {
              "color": "#83cead"
            }]
          }, {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
              "visibility": "on"
            }, {
              "color": "#ffffff"
            }]
          }, {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [{
              "visibility": "off"
            }]
          }, {
            "featureType": "road.highway",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
              "visibility": "on"
            }, {
              "color": "#fee379"
            }]
          }, {
            "featureType": "road.arterial",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
              "visibility": "on"
            }, {
              "color": "#fee379"
            }]
          }, {
            "featureType": "water",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
              "visibility": "on"
            }, {
              "color": "#7fc8ed"
            }]
          }]
        };

        // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
        // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
        var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

        // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

        // Let's also add a marker while we're at it
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400),
          map: map,
          title: 'Snazzy!'
        });
      }
    </script>

    <!-- FLAT DESIGN MAP -->
</section>
</div>
```